# Fontawesome icons not showing up on "./mvnw" start of angular but do show up on "npm start"

Tags: angular, maven, font-awesome, jhipster

Fontawesome icons not working properly in angular project.

So I am basically having a problem with fontawesome icons. If I use  tag, that only works for the icons already in navigation bar by default, I do not know how to add custom ones (like envelope for example). Hence I added fontawesome .css to index.html and used good old  to insert icons. That works just fine when I start up the front end with "npm start" na open up localhost:9000, but it does not work when I start up "./mvnw" and open up localhost:8080. What could be the problem ? I basically need any solution to use any free fontawesome icon I want.

index.html ->

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

app.module.ts ->

```
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';
imports: [AngularFontAwesomeModule]
```

navbar.component.html ->

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

No error messages. It simply doesn't show up, like I never added .css file.

Answer (score 1):

To import new icons in a JHipster project, add the icon in [`vendor.ts`](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/046e39bf358891ae1c87ec92389465919ffd2699/src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts).  The library is configured this way to only include icons that are used, and to not package the unused icons in production builds.

Ignore the `.....` in the code below, it means there is other content.  Shortened to fit in an answer.

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import {
  faUser,
  faSort,
  .....
  faEnvelope
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

// Adds the SVG icon to the library so you can use it in your page
library.add(faUser);
library.add(faSort);
....
library.add(faEnvelope);
```

Then you can use the regular font-awesome tag for including the envelope icon:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faEnvelope"></fa-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't import the icon itself. This solved the problem :

navbar.component.ts ->

```
import { faEnvelope } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
expored class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
    faEnvelope = faEnvelope
}
```

navbar.component.html ->

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faEnvelope"></fa-icon>
```